# passport-azure-ad Single Sign On (SSO)

Tags: azure, authentication, single-sign-on, passport.js, passport-azure-ad

I am trying to set up authentication thru Azure AD for my website built with React, NodeJS, and Express using the passport-azure-ad package. Authentication works successfully and I am able to authenticate and retrieve a token, but the login prompt appears when logging in even if I have a logged in session on admin.microsoft.com or sharepoint.mytenant.com. I know the passport-azure-ad documentation says it is possible to use single-sign-on, but I have not been able to find any guidance on how to set it up.

passport strategy:

```
passport.use(new OIDCStrategy(
  {
    identityMetadata: `${process.env.OAUTH_ID_METADATA}`,
    clientID: process.env.OAUTH_APP_ID,
    responseType: 'code id_token',
    responseMode: 'form_post',
    redirectUrl: process.env.OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI,
    allowHttpForRedirectUrl: true,
    clientSecret: process.env.OAUTH_APP_PASSWORD,
    passReqToCallback: false,
    scope: process.env.OAUTH_SCOPES.split(' ')
  },
  signInComplete
));
```

signInComplete: users are currently stored in memory rather than a db. Uses simple-oath2.

```
async function signInComplete(iss, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, params, done) {
  if (!profile.oid) {
    return done(new Error("No OID found in user profile."));
  }

  try{
    console.log('in here');
    const user = await graph.getUserDetails(accessToken);

    if (user) {
      // Add properties to profile
      profile['email'] = user.mail ? user.mail : user.userPrincipalName;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return done(err);
  }

  // Create a simple-oauth2 token from raw tokens
  let oauthToken = oauth2.accessToken.create(params);

  // Save the profile and tokens in user storage
  users[profile.oid] = { profile, oauthToken };
  return done(null, users[profile.oid]);
}
```

Authorization functions:

```
/* GET auth callback. */
router.get('/signin',
  function  (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', 
      {
        response: res,
        prompt: 'login',
        failureRedirect: '/',
        successRedirect: '/'
      }
    )(req,res,next);
  }
);

// <CallbackRouteSnippet>
router.post('/callback',
  function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect',
      {
        response: res,
        failureRedirect: '/',
        successRedirect: '/'
      }
    )(req,res,next);
  }
);
// </CallbackRouteSnippet>

router.get('/signout',
  function(req, res) {
    req.session.destroy(function(err) {
      req.logout();
      res.redirect('/');
    });
  }
);
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please refer to this [sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad) it may help you.

Comment: Please checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76873146/10030693

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this sample it may help you
https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad

The sample passport-azure-ad has been tested to work with both Microsoft Azure Active Directory and with Microsoft Active Directory Federation Services.

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_3JlaV8EPqEViNWB&Q_CHL=gl
>